# React slick how to enable no pause

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

i am trying to create infinite slideshow without pause
this are my settings for the react-slick slider

```
const settings = {
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 5000,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  arrows: false,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  easing: "linear"
};
```

this is the closest i was able to achieve but i'm 
still getting a slight pause

i would like to know if this even possible with react-slick or maybe there are other libraries that will match my needs

Comment: how much images you are trying to show? (overall)

Comment: iam trying to show 4 images

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const settings = {
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 10000,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  arrows: false,
};
```

Comment: thanks this is way better
but there is still a little delay after the last image 
there is any way i can avoid it  ?

Comment: I don't see any pauses when I try it on my app. It scrolls smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

```
{dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  initialSlide: 0,
  arrows: false,
  autoplay: true,
  speed: 2000,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  cssEase: "linear",}
```

I think the speed and autoplaySpeed should have the same value, this works for me
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/auto-play/